# How to debug javascript implementation In V8

Tags: javascript, debugging, v8

I'm learning v8 now, but I have encountered some problems.
How to set a breakpoint a method's start address in memory if I want to debug a method's C++ implementation. 
e.g. `var a= new Array(0,1); a.indexOf(1) ;` I want to set a breakpoint at slice's beginning, or are there other ways to track the assembler code ?

There are a lot of functions will be complied and writed into a file named snapshot.bin. so I can't set a breakpoint at the beginning of these functions.

Comment: I'm sorry to write a wrong example/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the source code and find the implementation of `slice`. Then set a gdb/lldb break point in that .cc file: [byiltins-typedarray.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/builtins/builtins-typedarray.cc?q=TypedArrayPrototypeSli&sq=package:chromium&l=280)

A lot of functions are defined as builtin or runtime functions.

Comment: I'm sorry to write a wrong example. There are a lot of functions will be complied and writed into a file named snapshot.bin. so I can't set a breakpoint at the beginning of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of function you want to inspect.

You can compile without snapshot to get around snapshot-related debugging difficulties (at the cost of making startup quite a bit slower: several seconds in Debug mode).

You can modify the respective code generator to emit a break instruction at the beginning of the function. For the example of Array.indexOf, that's probably the easiest solution; the `CodeStubAssembler` instruction is called `DebugBreak()`.

You can break somewhere else using GDB, find your way to the function in question (e.g. via isolate->builtins), and set a breakpoint on the address of its entry. (This requires a bit of V8 knowledge and/or code reading skills, but it's not difficult.)

You can use various `--print-*-code` flags to print code to stdout (without breaking on it).

Comment: It always be failed when I add DebugBreak in CSA functions.  FAILED: gen/embedded.cc snapshot_blob.bin
G:/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_6_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../tools/run.py ./mksnapshot --turbo_instruction_scheduling --embedded_src gen/embedded.cc --embedded_variant Default --random-seed 314159265 --startup_blob snapshot_blob.bin

Comment: Sure, DebugBreak will emit a break instruction ("int3" on x86). You'll have to run the binary (mksnapshot in this case) in a debugger, so you can stop and resume at that break instruction. Or you can compile without snapshot if you find it easier to debug the d8 binary instead.